# Add an external jQuery based library

Tags: javascript

How can we add an external javascript library that relies on jQuery by calling $(document)??

As Drupal 7's jQuery needs to be encapsulated, adding the library just generates errors:

> $(...) is not a function

I don't understand the point of not being able to use $ directly anymore.
And adding jQuery as an external library seems to conflict with the Drupal's one

Thanks for the help

Comment: What are you doing with the library? I ask, because if you're using it within your custom code, you should call it from within a function that's already name spaced and there shouldn't be an issue.  The reason for not being able to use `$` without name spacing it is to avoid conflicting with other JavaScript frameworks

Comment: Also what library are you using. It may be that library is poorly written and it assumes global `$` pointing to `jQuery`.

Comment: This is the library I wanted to add:
https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

"it assumes global $ pointing to jQuery" is interesting. Does it mean there is way to execute jQuery from firebug for example? So far since Drupal 7 I havent been able

Comment: have you tried jQuery(...) instead?

Comment: The fastclick library you referenced does not require jQuery, so you shouldn't need to write any jQuery code to initialize the library.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`drupal_add_js()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) for this.

Please also check [these](https://drupal.org/project/javascript_libraries) [resources](https://drupal.org/project/libraries); they could help you out.

For using other versions of jQuery, there is the [jQuery Update](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the links. I have actually added it via the theme.info, drupal_add_js, and dirty injection in template.php. Always the same result. I believe it has something to do with what Ihor said: "(the library) assumes global $ pointing to jQuery"

Answer (score 1):

You can add javascript library in your custom theme in preprocess-html.inc 
e.g.

```
 drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'themename') . '/js/fastclick.min.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try, it will assign $ to be jQuery. It's not the correct way to do this, but it seems like that 3rd party library did things wrong to begin with.

```
drupal_add_js('$ = jQuery;', array(
  'type' => 'inline', 
  'scope' => 'header', 
  'group' => JS_LIBRARY,
  'weight' => -1,
));
```

There is a module that does roughly the same thing: https://drupal.org/project/jquery_dollar

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it sounds like there may be two questions here, external libraries and using the dollar sign jQuery variable.

1) I use the Libraries API module to add external libraries that my custom modules need. It makes your code a little more concise I suppose: https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries

**Note:** I'd add that I've never had a 3rd parties jQuery mess with Drupal's jQuery using the Libraries API.

2) I use the following code to prevent my jQuery code from conflicting with Drupal's jQuery in my module and theme jQuery:

```
(function ($) { 

  $(window).resize(function(){
    // Do something
  });  

})(jQuery);
```